# Stacking Display Objects dynamically leaves a small gap (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to create a menu where display objects are stacked against each other dynamically. However I always get a small gap on some of the stacked objects.

This is in a loop where i gets incremented

```
    curr_item.height = 25;
    curr_item.x = 5;        
    curr_item.y = i* (curr_item.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely anti-aliasing. Some `height` or `y` in the display is not an exact integer. It could be the contents `curr_item` is not exactly 25, or the `y` position is somehow not an integer, or the `y` position of any parent of `curr_item` is not an integer.